# Simple Logger erroring on init

Tags: logging, rust

I am building a Rust app and I am using [Simple Logger](https://crates.io/crates/simple_logger) to log the init of my app. My `main.rs` looks like this:

```rust
use log::info;
use simple_logger::SimpleLogger;

fn main() {
    SimpleLogger::new().init().unwrap();


    let (event_loop, mut interface) = create_interface();
    info!("Game interface created");
```

the above code is erroring with:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Could not determine the UTC offset on this system. Possible causes are that the time crate does not implement "local_offset_at" on your system, or that you are running in a multi-threaded environment and the time crate is returning "None" from "local_offset_at" to avoid unsafe behaviour. See the time crate's documentation for more information. (https://time-rs.github.io/internal-api/time/index.html#feature-flags): IndeterminateOffset', /home/athul/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/simple_logger-1.16.0/src/lib.rs:409:85
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I've tried:

- using `try_current_local_offset` with the time crate
- using Chrono

but the error still persists. It's likely that I do not have my time properly initialized for my app. What is the best (and easiest) way to do it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using a minimal example. Have you already tried to use `.with_utc_timestamps()` like mentioned here https://github.com/ravenclaw900/DietPi-Dashboard/issues/82 respectively https://github.com/ravenclaw900/DietPi-Dashboard/commit/a3853c2697d5a0606499c41fc6cf456543e01a4e ?

Comment: this worked :) please this as an answer and ill mark it as solved :) thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the comment suggestion from Benjamin Brootz worked. So here's the solution:

```rust
SimpleLogger::new().with_utc_timestamps().init().unwrap();
```

this creates a logger instance with a UTC time stamp. All credits to the said user :)

Comment: I have code from last year without the `with_utc_timestamps` that worked (and still does).  I am refactoring it into a new repo, but it panics without the utc call. Has something changed recently (I still have old dependencies in the old project)?